# Retrieving data from rich text editor in spfx web part properties

Tags: web-part, spfx-webparts, react, rich-text, spfx-custom-property-pane

I am currently creating a custom web part, the webpart is using PropertyFieldCollectionData to collect user data (https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/). I want the user to be able to use a rich text editor so I am using the customFieldId within PropertyFieldCollectionData to render my own controls.
I am using it to render the CKeditor and have also tried JoditEditor.

```
                {
                  id: "customFieldId",
                  title: "Custom Field",
                  type: CustomCollectionFieldType.custom,
                  onCustomRender: (field, value, item, itemId, onUpdate) => {
                    return (
                      React.createElement(Editor)

                    )
                  }
                }
```

it renders the editor 
[image]
But I am not able to access any of the values that the user has entered in my webpart. How can I get the values entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would come back and share what my code looks like after finally getting this to work. Just in case it can help any one!

```
{
                      id: "description",
                      title: strings.descriptionField,
                      type: CustomCollectionFieldType.custom,
                      onCustomRender: (field, value, onUpdate, item, itemId, onError) => {
                        return (
                          React.createElement("div", null,
                            React.createElement(CKEditor, {
                              data: value,
                              editor: ClassicEditor,
                              key: itemId,
                              value: value,
                              config: editorConfig,
                              onInit: (editor: any) => { 
                                editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader: any) => {
                                  return new UploadAdapter(loader);
                               };
                              },
                              onChange: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => {
                                const data = editor.getData();
                                onUpdate(field.id, data);
                              }
                            }
                            )
                          )
                        );
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the value would have to be passed to the `onUpdate` function on your `onCustomRender` property.

You can see how this is done in the bottom example on the page you linked:

```
01. {
02.   id: "customFieldId",
03.   title: "Custom Field",
04.   type: CustomCollectionFieldType.custom,
05.   onCustomRender: (field, value, onUpdate, item, itemId, onError) => {
06.     return (
07.       React.createElement("div", null,
08.        React.createElement("input", { key: itemId, value: value, onChange: (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
09.           if (event.currentTarget.value === "error") {
10.            onError(field.id, "Value shouldn't be equal to error");
11.          } else {
12.            onError(field.id, "");
13.          }
14.          onUpdate(field.id, event.currentTarget.value);
15.        }}), " "
16.      )
17.    );
18.  }
19. }
```

Here, the `input`element will fire the onChange event when it updates. (line 8)

In `React.createElement`this is passed along to `onUpdate` after some validation (line 14).

`onCustomRender` will then set the value of `this.properties.customFieldId`to the updated value.

You will have to check the properties of the component you are using to see how this is done for that and adjust your `React.createElement` accordingly...